# Is this semicolon acceptable? "How to Thrive & Create Joy at Work; the major conference hosted by Google"

Tags: punctuation, semicolons

Is the semicolon in the below sentence acceptable?

> How to Thrive & Create Joy at Work; the major conference hosted by Google, seeks to inspire...

I feel like it's not, but I see sentences like this everywhere, often by people who write professionally, so I'm trying to validate my understanding.

Comment: The semi-colon has seriously fallen out of favour in modern times. In the above, you could put the conference title in quotes and leave out the semi-colon.Modern usage also minimises commas so you can leave out the comma after the conference title.

Comment: You are quite right. Whoever wrote that sentence either didn't proofread it or didn't do a good job proofreading it. Fortunately, the meaning seems to be quite clear despite the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "the major conference hosted by Google" is in apposition to "How to Thrive & Create Joy at Work." Non-restrictive appositives such as this one are always set off by commas. A semicolon makes no sense here. https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/596/01/

Answer (score -1):

[OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/semicolon) has the following to say on the use of the semicolon:

> The main task of the semicolon is to mark a break that is stronger
>   than a comma but not as final as a full stop. It’s used between two
>   main clauses that balance each other and are too closely linked to be
>   made into separate sentences

The break between : 'How to Thrive & Create Joy at Work' and 'the major conference hosted by Google' would not be as strong if a comma was used.

Also OLD goes on to say:

> You can also use a semicolon as a stronger division in a sentence that
>   already contains commas.

There is at least one other comma in your example sentence, semantically the stronger break gives more weight to the fact that the conference is a 'major conference hosted by Google' , than that it 'seeks to inspire...' which would make sense.

These matters often come down to a point of style, but from a technical point of view, there's nothing wrong with the use.

Comment: But surely neither the part before or after the semicolon could be considered to be a main clause? Oxford Dictionaries describes a main clause as 'A clause that can form a complete sentence standing alone, having a subject and a predicate.'